# Why am I getting 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file' ? full code shown Pycharm/Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I've looked through similar Q's but none of the answers seem to sort my issue.

I am running a test 'test_HomePage' via Pycharm (Python 3.9) with Pytest as the test runner

Code as follows:

Conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = None

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    
    global driver
    browser_name=request.config.getoption("browser_name")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe")

    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
    driver.maximize_window()

    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```

Baseclass.py:

```
import inspect
import logging

import pytest
import TestData.HomePageData
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:

    def getLogger(self):
        loggerName = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        logger = logging.getLogger(loggerName)
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s :%(levelname)s : %(name)s :%(message)s")
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)  # filehandler object

        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        return logger

    def verifyLinkPresence(self, text):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, text)))

    def selectOptionByText(self,locator,text):
        sel = Select(locator)
        sel.select_by_visible_text(text)
```

test_HomePage.py:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest

from TestData.HomePageData import HomePageData
from pageObjects.HomePage import HomePage
from utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass

class TestHomePage(BaseClass):

    def test_formSubmission(self,getData):
        log = self.getLogger()
        homepage= HomePage(self.driver)
        log.info("first name is "+getData["firstname"])
        homepage.getName().send_keys(getData["firstname"])
        homepage.getEmail().send_keys(getData["lastname"])
        homepage.getCheckBox().click()
        self.selectOptionByText(homepage.getGender(), getData["gender"])

        homepage.submitForm().click()

        alertText = homepage.getSuccessMessage().text

        assert ("Success" in alertText)
        self.driver.refresh()

    @pytest.fixture(params=HomePageData.getTestData("Testcase2"))
    def getData(self, request):
        return request.param
```

HomePageData.py:

```
class HomePageData:


    #data dictionary to pass to the 'test_homepage' test section
    test_HomePage_data = [{"firstname": "Matt", "lastname": "Smith", "gender": "Male"}, {"firstname": "Jane", "lastname": "Smith", "gender": "Female"}]


import openpyxl


class HomePageData:
    test_HomePage_data = [{"firstname": "Matt", "lastname": "Smith", "gender": "Male"},
                          {"firstname": "Jane", "lastname": "Smith", "gender": "Female"}]

    #below is for using excel data import in the place of the above data line
    #static method declared, so 'self' is not required prior to 'test_case_name'
    @staticmethod
    def getTestData(test_case_name):
        Dict = {}
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\PythonExcel\\PythonDemo.xlsx")
        sheet = book.active
        for i in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):  # to get rows
            if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value == test_case_name:

                for j in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):  # to get columns
                    # Dict["lastname"]="shetty
                    Dict[sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value] = sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value
        return[Dict]
```

Screenshot showing folder/file structure:

[Folder structure within Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnHCt.png)

---

Full text of error received:

> U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2021.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path U:/PythonMN/SeleniumFramework/tests/test_HomePage.py -- -s -v Testing started at 11:31 ... Launching pytest with arguments -s -v
> U:/PythonMN/SeleniumFramework/tests/test_HomePage.py --no-header
> --no-summary -q in U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\tests
>
> ============================= test session starts ============================= collected 1 item
>
> test_HomePage.py::TestHomePage::test_formSubmission[getData0]
> -INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py",
> line 269, in wrap_session
> -INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py",
> line 323, in _main
> -INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py",
> line 286, in **call**
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 93, in _hookexec
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 84, in 
> -INTERNALERROR>     self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 208, in _multicall
> -INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 80, in get_result
> -INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnHCt.png).with_traceback(ex[2])
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 187, in _multicall
> -INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py",
> line 348, in pytest_runtestloop
> -INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py",
> line 286, in **call**
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 93, in _hookexec
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 84, in 
> -INTERNALERROR>     self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 208, in _multicall
> -INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 80, in get_result
> -INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnHCt.png).with_traceback(ex[2])
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 187, in _multicall
> -INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py",
> line 109, in pytest_runtest_protocol
> -INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py",
> line 120, in runtestprotocol
> -INTERNALERROR>     rep = call_and_report(item, "setup", log)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py",
> line 217, in call_and_report
> -INTERNALERROR>     report: TestReport = hook.pytest_runtest_makereport(item=item, call=call)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py",
> line 286, in **call**
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 93, in _hookexec
> -INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py",
> line 84, in 
> -INTERNALERROR>     self._inner_hookexec = lambda hook, methods, kwargs: hook.multicall(
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py",
> line 203, in _multicall
> -INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\tests\conftest.py", line 48, in
> pytest_runtest_makereport
> -INTERNALERROR>     _capture_screenshot(file_name)
> -INTERNALERROR>   File "U:\PythonMN\SeleniumFramework\tests\conftest.py", line 57, in
> _capture_screenshot
> -INTERNALERROR>     driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
> -INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file'
>
> ============================ no tests ran in 0.82s ============================
>
> Process finished with exit code 3

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `driver` object is not instantiated inside the `_capture_screenshot` method.
Not instantiated variables are defined as `None` type objects in Python.
Obviously such objects do not have methods and attributes of `webdriver` class

Comment: I've actually found the issue, and I'm kicking myself - chromedriver file location in the conftest.py was wrong - was c:\chromedriver.exe, should have been c:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe

Comment: although it dint solve the issue which was down to my glaring mistake as detailed above, thanks for your reply!